# ruby backup runs fine from command line, fails as crontab

Tags: ruby, unix, cron

I have a bash script that 1) backs up my app using the `backup` gem and 2) uploads the result to my Box account.

```
#!/usr/bash

PATH=/etc/profile:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
cd ~
backup perform --no-quiet -t eds_backup > ~/output.txt
#use Python script to send archive to Box
source `which activate` box_backup
python ~/box_backup/main.py
```

When run manually from the command line it runs as expected. But when I set it up as a crontab it fails. Here's the crontab.

```
PATH=/etc/profile:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
* * * * *  bash -lc ~/scripts/backup.bash > /tmp/eds_backup.output
```

`/tmp/eds_backup.output` is an empty file after this job runs.

Here is the contents of the backup model. The passwords for email and database are kept in /etc/profile

```
Model.new(:eds_backup, 'Back up for my project') do

  archive :my_archive do |archive|
    # Run the `tar` command using `sudo`
    # archive.use_sudo
    archive.add "path/to/my/project"
  end

  store_with Local do |local|
    local.path       = "/where/to/store/backup"

  end

  compress_with Gzip

    notify_by Mail do |mail|
      mail.on_success           = true
      mail.on_warning           = true
      mail.on_failure           = true

      mail.from                 = "me@email.com"
      mail.to                   = "me@email.com"
      #mail.cc                   = "cc@email.com"
      #mail.bcc                  = "bcc@email.com"
      mail.reply_to             = "me@email.com"
      mail.address              = "smtp.office365.com"
      mail.port                 = 587
      mail.domain               = "mydomain.com"
      mail.user_name            = "me@email.com"
      mail.password             = ENV['EMAIL_PW']  #this variable is kept in /etc/profile
      mail.authentication       = :login
      mail.encryption           = :starttls
    end

  database MySQL do |db|

    db.name               = "dbname"
    db.username           = "db_user"
    db.password           = ENV['EDSACCESS_PW'] #this variable is kept in /etc/profile
    db.host               = "localhost"
    db.port               = 3306

    db.prepare_backup = true # see https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup/pull/606 for more information
  end

end
```

The `backup` log has no output.

Finally here is the output given by /var/log/syslog

```
Apr  8 15:48:01 edsdata CRON[25092]: (stoebelj) CMD (bash -lc ~/scripts/backup.bash > /tmp/eds_backup.output)
Apr  8 15:48:01 edsdata CRON[25091]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I've given global permission to execute the bash script. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

To simplify things, I've edited my crontab like so

```
* * * * * backup perform --no-quiet -t eds_backup
```

Backup implicitly keeps its own log and no new entries appear after waiting a few minutes. It appears that the crontab isn't calling anything

Comment: I've always had trouble with `cron` using io redirection (`>`) and relative paths (`~`). Can your Ruby program write to a file instead of stdout? Also, I see your schedule is just a bunch of asterisks. Are you sure your first instance isn't just locking the file and then fighting for permissions? Check `ps` to see if it finishes in time. You could also try writing to a timestamped file, say /tmp/eds_backup$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).output so you know two instances spawned at different times will never try to use the same file.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths? Did it make any difference?

Comment: Cron sends error messages by email so you should either install some MTA (sendmail / postfix or any other) as suggested in the `syslog` or you can simply redirect the standard error to a file in crontab and then you should get the error message there. Something like: `* * * * *  bash -lc ~/scripts/backup.bash > /tmp/eds_backup.output 2> /tmp/eds_backup.errors`. Can you show us the error?

Comment: The `which activate` part looks suspicious. Where do you expect to find that?

Comment: Try using `$HOME` instead of `~` in the crontab

Comment: To simplify things, I've edited my crontab like so

`* * * * * backup perform --no-quiet -t eds_backup`
Backup implicitly keeps its own log and no new entries appear after waiting a few minutes. It appears that the crontab isn't calling anything. Does this help narrow things down?